# Python visual text editor

Tags: python, text, editor

I have been coding in python on and off for that last one year. Mostly, i have been doing matlab and i was wondering if there was such a thing as a visual text editor for python. Something like the matlab editor itself which lets you visualize your code?

Comment: i thought you had to pay for PyCharm. I was trying to look for something that was free so i could explore it more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Spyder (https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/). If you're coming from the Matlab world, then this can feel familiar to you. You have plotting capabilities like in Matlab, and you have the numpy library loaded by default, for matlab-like matrix computations.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot.